# How to increase LS_HEAP_SIZE in tar package of Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using `Logstash 5.2` tar package in Ubuntu  I am ruining `Logstsh` with command line , question is how to increase LS_HEAP_SIZE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [`config/jvm.options`](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/master/config/jvm.options) file, simply change the `-Xmx` size

By default it is:

```
-Xmx1g
```

You can change it to or whatever else value.

```
-Xmx2g
```